# A widget for a list or table with pictures in the cells in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a widget that act like a list with columns. The cells can have values as integers, strings or **pictures**.

The Tkinter own `Listbox` can not have columns. The `Treeview` is not able to have pictures as values (except the first column `#0`).

Are there any Tkinter extensions that could fit my needs? Or how could I create something like this myself?

Some example code that could be used as a basis for a answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    # or a Listbox!!!
    tree = ttk.Treeview(root,
                        columns = ('one'))
    tree.heading('one', text='one')
    tree.pack()

    tree.img = Image.new(mode='RGBA', size=(10, 20), color='red')
    tree.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tree.img)

    for i in range(50):
        tree.insert(parent='',
                   index=END,
                   image=tree.img,
                   text='',
                   values = i)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think you should be using python-3.x exclusively unless the issue is python3 specific. You're needlessly narrowing down your audience. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could create a grid class using `Label`s to show integers, strings, and images:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class LabelGrid(tk.Frame):
    """
    Creates a grid of labels that have their cells populated by content.
    """
    def __init__(self, master, content=([0, 0], [0, 0]), *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.content = content
        self.content_size = (len(content), len(content[0]))
        self._create_labels()
        self._display_labels()


    def _create_labels(self):
        def __put_content_in_label(row, column):
            content = self.content[row][column]
            content_type = type(content).__name__
            if content_type in ('str', 'int'):
                self.labels[row][column]['text'] = content
            elif content_type == 'PhotoImage':
                self.labels[row][column]['image'] = content


        self.labels = list()
        for i in range(self.content_size[0]):
            self.labels.append(list())
            for j in range(self.content_size[1]):
                self.labels[i].append(tk.Label(self))
                __put_content_in_label(i, j)


    def _display_labels(self):
        for i in range(self.content_size[0]):
            for j in range(self.content_size[1]):
                self.labels[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file="13.gif") # replace with your image
    label_grid = LabelGrid(root, ([3, img], ['my_string', 7]))
    label_grid.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I believe, `self.labels.append(list())` in `_display_labels` is excessive, isn't it?

Comment: @VadimShkaberda Yes I think so. Thanks, I removed it.